# Contractibility of Path space.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In the book of Martin Arkowitz, the author states that Path space is contractible because of the Homotopy $G: EX \times I \to EX, G(l,t)(s)= l(s+(1-s)t)$, where $EX$ is the space of paths ending at the base point of $X$.

My question is how to prove that this map $G$ is indeed continuous?

Is there any universal property of compact open topology which can be applied to deal with the construction of continuous maps from / to a space with compact open topology?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the universal property is that maps can be "curried" under mild technical conditions. If $X,Y,Z$ are topological spaces, a map $f\colon X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ induces a map $F\colon X\rightarrow Z^Y,\,x\mapsto(y\mapsto f(x,y))$, where $Z^Y$ is the space of maps $Y\rightarrow Z$ with the compact-open topology. If $Y$ is locally compact, the evaluation function $Z^Y\times Y\rightarrow Z,\,(f,y)\mapsto f(y)$ is continuous and this implies that the converse holds too, i.e. map $F\colon X\rightarrow Z^Y$ induces a map $f\colon  X\times Y\rightarrow Z,\,x\mapsto(y\mapsto F(x)(y))$. Thus, we get a one-to-one correspondence between continuous functions $X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ and $X\rightarrow Z^Y$. This holds in particular for the compact space $Y=I$. You can find the details in the appendix of Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).

Now, in your case, the function $G\colon EX\times I\rightarrow EX\subseteq X^I$ is continuous if and only if the curried function $EX\times I\times I\rightarrow X,\,(l,t,s)\mapsto l(s+(1-s)t)$ is continuous. This follows from the obvious continuity of $I\times I\rightarrow I,\,(t,s)\mapsto s+(1-s)t$ and the continuity of the evaluation map $EX\times I\subseteq X^I\times I\rightarrow X$.